# SQL Server: convert StartDATE 20140804 Nvarchar to Datetime2

Tags: sql-server, nvarchar, datetime2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I did an import from a flat file. I couldn't import the `datetime` column properly so I specified it temporarily as a `nvarchar(50)`.

Now I want to convert it to `datetime2` format. However when doing so, I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The data that is currently in my `nvarchar(50)` column looks like this:

```
20140804
```

And I need  to convert it to:

```
2014-08-04 00:00:00.0000000.
```

Note that I do not only want to convert one date, but all `StartDATE` values in my table and insert them to another table

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Insert into targettab(datecol,<othercols....>)
select cast(datefield as datetime2),<othercols...> from sourcetab
```

You can use `cast` function

Comment: Thank  You, this worked.  I also tried SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, StartDATE,12) which works fine. However for some reason when I process my EndDATE I receive the error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert to char first because converting to int adds those days to `1900-01-01`

```
select CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),rnwl_efctv_dt ))
```

here are some examples

```
select CONVERT (datetime,5)
1900-01-06 00:00:00.000

select CONVERT (datetime,20100101)
```

blows up, because you can't add 20100101 days to 1900-01-01..you go above the limit

convert to char first

```
declare @i int
select @i = 20100101
select CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),@i))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT convert(varchar, StartDATE , 113) from ur table
```

Comment: The OP wants to convert to `datetime2` - not to another type of string ...